# simple_form collection_Radio_buttons generates extra labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have the following Ruby:

```
<%= simple_form_for @answer, url: presentation_survey_path(@presentation) do |f| %>
                <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :option_id, @question.options_array, :first, :last, {label: false} do |b| %>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <%= b.label(class: 'btn btn-large', style: 'margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px;') {b.radio_button(id: b.object.last, class: 'answer-input', style: 'display: none;') + b.text } %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And it is correctly generating html except that it is generating two labels:

```
<span>
    <label for="answer_option_id_15">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="btn btn-large" for="answer_option_id_15" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px;">
                <input class="answer-input" id="Way too many" name="answer[option_id]" style="display: none;" type="radio" value="15" />
            Way too many
            </label>
        </div>
    </label>
</span>
```

It is gennerating the first label for some reason.  I only want to keep the second one.  Label: false is not working.  How do I get rid of the first label?

Comment: According to the docs, you've got it right, but the only difference is that you're injecting straight html in the lines between.  Can you drop that and see what happens?  If that works, try a content_tag, or try applying the class and style in js or css.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

> For check boxes and radio buttons you can remove the label changing
>   boolean_style from default value :nested to :inline.

In addition, `simple_form` has some options for `collection_radio_buttons` that are documented in the code:

> ```
> # Collection radio accepts some extra options:
> #
> #   * checked  => the value that should be checked initially.
> #
> #   * disabled => the value or values that should be disabled. Accepts a single
> #                 item or an array of items.
> #
> #   * collection_wrapper_tag   => the tag to wrap the entire collection.
> #
> #   * collection_wrapper_class => the CSS class to use for collection_wrapper_tag
> #
> #   * item_wrapper_tag         => the tag to wrap each item in the collection.
> #
> #   * item_wrapper_class       => the CSS class to use for item_wrapper_tag
> #
> #   * a block                  => to generate the label + radio or any other component.
> ```

In my case setting `item_wrapper_tag` to `false` and `boolean_style` to `:inline` did the trick, e.g.:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :option_id, @question.options_array, :first, :last, boolean_style: :inline, item_wrapper_tag: false do |b| %>
```